# Rendering a lot of components

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make a small application with VueJS and I am having some performance issues.

I'm not sure that this is something I can do something for, but asking anyway.

My goal is to render a lot of components (more than 10,000 at the same moment). But the time it takes to Vue to render thoses components and update the dom is quite long.

Here I made a small JsFiddle so you can try on your side: https://jsfiddle.net/rt5cjbby/

At home, with a badass i7 processor, it takes 400ms to render. Which is, much more when you test with more components.

My question is: Is there any technique I could use to have better performances?

Is it possible to update the DOM every 100 components to be rendered? The client could see the first 100 components very quickly then the browser would continue to render....

Here is my example code if you don't want to open jsFiddle:

```
some_table = []

for (let i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    some_table.push({
    foo: 'bar'
  })
}

let someComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '#some-component',
  props: ['input']
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    lines: some_table
  },
  components: {
    someComponent
  }
})
```

And my templates:

```
<div id="app">
  <div  v-for="line in lines">
    <some-component :input="line"></some-component>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="some-component">
  <div>
    {{ input.foo }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Of course, I could fill my table every 0.01s but I don't feel that this is the best solution.

PS: I accept responses like "[Angular|React] are better for your usecase **because** ...."

Thank you very much for your help/experiences/advices and have a nice day

Comment: I'm curious is it really necessary to render 10k components at once? I can't imagine a usage case.

Comment: I am building a MySQL explorer with Github Electron and VueJS, and every cell of the table must be a component. I would have liked to copy Sequel Pro behaviour that is displaying 1000 lines at a time. So it would make 1000 lines * number of columns of the table. Of course, when I come closer to 100-200 lines, performances are better but I would have liked to make this work with 1000 lines :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127869/vue-js-hiding-of-items-outside-current-viewport

Comment: @RoyJ thank you for the link, very interesting approach. However, I don't think that this would fit in my case as it is the creation of the components that are taking so much time, not the content of the component itself

Comment: The idea is that you would create components if the space a new component would go into is visible. So a screenful would be created, and creation would stop. On scroll, you'd check and create more as needed.

Comment: Yes, after writing my comment I think you are right. I just might fix the parent div to a fixed height, and add an additional v-if on the component if it is not visible. I am going to try that, I keep you informed, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in only *rendering* the component's end result, you can easily achieve exceptional performance utilizing the [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html).

Here is a complete working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39u72v6p/) of the following:

**Template:**

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
some_table = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  some_table.push({
    foo: 'bar'
  })
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    lines: some_table
  },
  render: function (createElement) {
    if (this.lines.length) {
      return createElement('div', this.lines.map(function (line) {
        return createElement('div', line.foo)
      }))
    } else {
      return createElement('p', 'No items found.')
    }
  }
})

setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    some_table.unshift({
      foo: 'bar stool'
    })
  }
}, 2500)
```

In this example, 10,000 "cells" are rendered almost immediately (about 450ms while profiling on my machine).  After a 2.5 second delay, an additional 10 new records are added as well, since the render function will respond to changes to the array.  This allows you to make changes to the rendered state as needed by modifying the source array.

Note that you can still perform complex 2-way data binding via your own v-model implementations in render functions, although it is significantly harder to maintain.

Comment: Impressive! Do you think that overpass the problem of unreadable code could be done with that kind of loader: https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx

Comment: @El_Matella I think there certainly could be significant advantages to using JSX in terms of maintainability and readability in this particular situation. I suspect you won't see quite the same performance since it is another layer of abstraction but I have not done a comparative test and the tradeoff may be worth it in your case.

Comment: Sure you can perfectly use jsx, but Vue single file components are the preferred way to go with VueJS, and should give very close performances, as they are pre-compiled too. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html